# Powermock - trying to mock method actually calls method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have a simple class with a static method which usually throws a null pointer:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static String s;

    public static final int myMethod(){
        return s.length();
    }
}
```

Im trying to mock this static method with PowerMock like this:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ MyClass.class })

public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        PowerMockito.mock(MyClass.class);
        when(MyClass.myMethod()).thenReturn(3);
        System.out.println(MyClass.myMethod());
    }
}
```

But the result is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyClass.myMethod(MyClass.java:6)
    at MyClassTest.test(MyClassTest.java:20)
```

So it seems the actual method was called when im trying to mock it. Why is that happening?

Comment: You should only mock dependencies, methods in your tested object are not good candidates for mocking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was i needed to use PowerMockito.mockStatic not PowerMockito.mock.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void test() {
        MyClass mockedClass = PowerMockito.mock(MyClass.class);
        when(mockedClass.myMethod()).thenReturn(3);
        System.out.println(MyClass.myMethod());
    }
```

Comment: Still same problem.